# Failed to back up: The specified object was not found. (0x80042308)

Tags: laptop, sony-vaio, windows-7-backup

I've been unable to backup my hard drive and I've been trying trying recommendations off of Google for quite a while, to no avail. When I try to backup files, I get the following error message:

> The backup did not complete successfully.  A shadow copy could not be
>   created for the following reason: The specified object was not found.
>   (0x80042308)

I tried to do [this solution](https://secure.efoldering.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/60/6/vss-error-vss_e_object_not_found-0x80042308) but in the second step there, when I right click on "Shared Folders" there is no "All Tasks" to choose:

[image]

Comment: Any reason not to use far superior 3rd party backup solutions?

Comment: @Karan: I thought it was a better idea to use the original windows which is installed on my laptop for a long time.

Comment: Use Windows, just don't use Windows Backup!

Comment: @Karan: That's a good idea! Unfortunately it doesn't let me use recovery options unless I use Windows backup.

Comment: I don't understand. You mean to say you cannot restore the data if you back it up using a 3rd party backup solution? Why not?

Comment: @Karan: What do you mean by a third party backup solution? I don't understand it myself, but I don't seem to be able to restore it to its factory condition this time!

Comment: There are good suggestions here: [Looking for a software capable of cloning a System drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/61317/looking-for-a-software-capable-of-cloning-a-system-drive) They will enable you to create full drive or per partition backups that you can restore any time.